# Adobe-illustrator: Soft-Cut group into two parts

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency, mask

I'm trying to cut a group of layers into two pieces, but I don't want a clear cut but the pieces should overlap and have a gradient-like border.

Can I do this with a opacity-mask?
Every time I export them as png there is an area in the overlap that has alpha < 100%, even though the two layers should add up to 100%.

Example(Left above each other, right a moved aside):

[image: test image]

Comment: Please, elaborate on your answer.

Comment: There is no answer here (as yet), thats why I'm asking?!

Comment: What is the purpose of your question?

Comment: I mean question, sorry.

Comment: I'd like to know how I can cut my group into two pieces so that the two pieces places above each other look like the previous group.

Comment: I did not understand too.